Check if permissions exist on WebRTC navigator.mediaDevices
Desired goal:
User enters page. If access / permissions is already granted on navigator.mediaDevices enumerate devices and show a drop-down from where to choose.
If no permissions display a connect button which upon click does navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, which displays the grant browser internal option. If granted enumerate devices.
I do not want to do the getUserMedia upon user entering the page as:

There is other utilities that does not require User Media, only require audio, optionally audio/video etc.
Find the built-in popup when entering a site asking for permission extremely obtrusive, ugly,  distracting and so on.

I want the user to be presented by a short informative description before clicking "open" device(s) if needed.

Obstacle:
I can use enumerateDevices and check if device.label is empty or not. But not sure if this is reliable. It should always be empty when no access granted, but does devices always get a label when access is granted? Is this a reliable check?
Have searched around and read on MDN but can not find any API-point on this.
(Secondary I wonder if there is a way to revoke access from JavaScript. As in displaying a button that revokes granted access. (Guess I might have to ask that as a separate question.))

Edit: (Forgot to include.) As per w3 spec it say
https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-datachannel-label

label of type USVString, readonly
The label attribute represents a label that can be used to distinguish
this RTCDataChannel object from other RTCDataChannel objects. Scripts
are allowed to create multiple RTCDataChannel objects with the same
label. On getting, the attribute MUST return the value of the
[[DataChannelLabel]] slot.

But not sure if this is the correct place to look at it + as noted on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo#instance_properties

Note: For security reasons, the label field is always blank unless an
active media stream exists or the user has granted persistent
permission for media device access. The set of device labels could
otherwise be used as part of a fingerprinting mechanism to identify a
user.

But again, not sure if label is always set when granted.

you are linking to the datachannel label which is a very different label.

@PhilippHancke Thank you. Yes, it was a rather ad-hock (No RTFM) addition from a somewhat impatient questioner a tad focused on getting past this rabbit hole (In the grand scheme of things).

enumerateDevices and checking the device labels is a pretty good way to check if a persistent permission exists. The permissions API supports this as well
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query
but may be less interoperable.
Chrome is also testing a new way to achieve this, described in https://developer.chrome.com/blog/permission-element-origin-trial?hl=en

Great. Can not upvote due to rep score, but greatly appreciate it. Find working with media-devices somewhat clunky as in it seems somewhat a product of ad-hock evolution then a broadly discussed platform. Comparing with RFCs is perhaps not fair. Especially due to the nature of browsers, the browser wars etc.
